# UITableView checkmarks duplicated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I keep getting checkmarks being marked in other sections of my table view when I click a row. Im not certain if I need to set my accessoryType. I tried `mytableView.reloadData()` however that didn't help either.

```
 var selected = [String]()
 var userList = [Users]()

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func createGroup(_ sender: Any) {

    for username in self.selected{

        ref?.child("Group").childByAutoId().setValue(username)

        print(username)
    }

}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    myCell.nameLabel.text = userList[indexPath.row].name
    return myCell
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark{

        myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
       let currentUser = userList[indexPath.row]
        selected = selected.filter { $0 != currentUser.name}
    }
    else{
        myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        let currentUser = userList[indexPath.row]
        selected.append(currentUser.name!)
    }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not inside this method but in the one that "loads" the cells. (cell for row)

Since Table Views use reusable cells, more often than not they will be loading a cell that was already presented somewhere else.

Because of this, on the cell loading method you should "Reset the state" the loaded cell, this includes the accessory type, and any other properties you might have changed.

So just change this in your code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    myCell.nameLabel.text = userList[indexPath.row].name

    // ADD THIS
    if userList[indexPath.row].isSelected {
        myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    } else {
        myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }

    return myCell
}
```

EDIT:

"userList[indexPath.row].isSelected" is a property that YOU have to create and manage. (So you must also modify it in the didSelectRowAt method.

Comment: this helped but now after a row is selected and I scroll down and back up the tableView the selected row is no longer checked.

Comment: You are supposed to "save" the state of which cells are selected. So your data source must have this information as well. Something like:
  userList[indexPath.row].isSelected

Comment: I would suggest you use a `Set<NSIndexPath>` to store your selected index paths.

Comment: i am getting an error on this line 'if userList[indexPath.row].isSelected' stating value of type User has no member '.isSelected'

Comment: Because it's just an example... You have to implement that somehow, an external array, or a property inside UserList class, or something. Your code seems to have the "selected" array so just use that, like check if the selected array contains value "userList[indexPath.row].name". If it does mark it as selected. Or store the index paths directly as Paulw11 mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are not maintaining the selected User info properly, which will be used while you scroll the table and when the cell has to reload data.

As you have already created   `var selected = [String]()` , I suggest using the same.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    let dataFoundInselectedArr =  selected.filter { $0 == userList[indexPath.row].name}

    if(dataFoundInselectedArr.count > 0){
          myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.checkmark
    }else{
          myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    }

    myCell.nameLabel.text = userList[indexPath.row].name
    return myCell
}
```

The table selection delegate method remains the same.

Comment: for myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.checkmark. has no member checkmark. I tried changing it to default however the checkmarks were still being duplicated

Comment: check my updated answer or simply use an imageview and set checkbox image as per the above condition.

Comment: changing it to myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.checkmark also brings the same error 'has no member checkmark' and the same error now also comes for myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

Comment: I suggest to use an imageview instead with two images of checkbox_deselect & checkbox_selected images and set the image according to current logic.