# how to set the selected check mark as ticked in tableview cell swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am using one `UITableView` to select the country with tick mark. But when I move to other screen and when I come back my check mark is invisible. It seems like the country what I am selecting is fine, But after I move to other screen an come back, The selected tick mark is not there. How to do that in swift.

**my code :**

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIButton!
    var languageName : String = String()

    var option : [String] = ["English","हिंदी"]
    var option1 : [String] = []
    let availableLanguages = Localize.availableLanguages()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        for language in availableLanguages {
            option1.append(language)
            let displayName = Localize.displayNameForLanguage(language)

        }

    }




    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }



    //MARK: - TableView
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return option1.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = option[indexPath.row]

        if option1[indexPath.row] == languageName{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        languageName = option1[indexPath.row]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        Localize.setCurrentLanguage(languageName)
        if let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appdelegate.showHomeLandingScreen()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView checkmarks duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814496/uitableview-checkmarks-duplicated)

Comment: Where you are setting the `countryName` ?

Comment: How it is related to `countryName` what I have asked where your setting the value in countryName ? What you are showing is declaration of some other Instance properties.

Comment: does `countryName` will remain same when you navigate back !!

Comment: @NiravD   I HAVE updated my full code here  . now country name is language name....if i get solution for this,..i can implement same for other screen also

Answer (score 2):

1) create another array of selected items and save it there are so many options eg. `UserDefaults.standard`

2) then compare with `option1[indexPath.row]`

example

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedLanguageArray, forKey: "selectedLanguageArray")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Then get it by

```
UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "selectedLanguageArray")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. create another array of selected items
2. here  option1[indexPath.row] compare this element with all element of another array

Here you go:-

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIButton!
    var languageName : String = String()

    var option : [String] = ["English","हिंदी"]
    var selectedlang: [String] = []

    let availableLanguages = Localize.availableLanguages()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        for language in availableLanguages {
            option1.append(language)
            let displayName = Localize.displayNameForLanguage(language)

        }

    }




    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }



    //MARK: - TableView
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return option1.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = option[indexPath.row]


        for (index,element) in selectedlang.enumerated(){

            if element == option[indexPath.row]{

                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark


            }else{

                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none



            }


        }
         return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        languageName = option1[indexPath.row]



        for (index,element) in newArr.enumerated(){

            if element == languageName{

                selectedlang.remove(at: index)

            }else{

                selectedlang.append(languageName)


            }


        }



        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        Localize.setCurrentLanguage(languageName)
        if let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appdelegate.showHomeLandingScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have created array like selectedlang = []. but dont know where to declare..can u please use my above code to help me where i need to put on exact

Comment: now not even showing that tick check mark when i select any option form table view...and also not showing the selected option

Comment: i dont have any idea about the table view...because of i dont have time now to learn from scrach..so only i have posted in so..atleast i can get the answer and it will help for me to resolve once again if i get any in future

Comment: but this concept is much okay...but without knowing to applay i dont know how to solve that....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar code that I use to save News category selections, should help you with your problem.

Saves multiple values that are checked.

```
class ViewController {
    var selectedCategoriesArray = [Any]()

    private var appSettings: UserDefaults?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        appSettings = UserDefaults.standard
        loadNewsSelectedCategories()
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellNewsCategory", for: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell...
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(newsCategoriesArray[indexPath.row])"
    let cellText: String? = cell?.textLabel?.text
    for lbl: String in selectedNewsCategories {
        if (cellText == lbl) {
            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            break
        }
        else {
            cell?.accessoryType = []
        }
    }
    return cell!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let selectedCell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let selectedCategory: String? = selectedCell?.textLabel?.text
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == [] {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        print("\(selectedCategory)")
        selectedCategoriesArray += selectedNewsCategories
        selectedCategoriesArray.append(selectedCategory)
        let categories: [Any] = NSOrderedSet(selectedCategoriesArray).array()
        print("+categories:\n \(categories)")
        appSettings["selectedNewsCategories"] = categories
    }
else if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = []
    print("\(selectedCategory)")
    loadNewsSelectedCategories()
    selectedCategoriesArray += selectedNewsCategories
selectedCategoriesArray.remove(at: selectedCategoriesArray.index(of: selectedCategory)!)

    var categories: [Any] = NSOrderedSet(selectedCategoriesArray).array()
    print("-categories:\n \(categories)")
    appSettings["selectedNewsCategories"] = categories
}
else {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = []
}
appSettings.synchronize()
}
func loadNewsSelectedCategories() {
    selectedNewsCategories = [Any]()
    selectedNewsCategories = appSettings["selectedNewsCategories"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please use below code which i corrected and tested, It stores last changed language and will get it even when you move other screen an come back**

//  ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIButton!
    var languageName : String?

    var option : [String] = ["English","हिंदी","French","Dutch"] //Your languages displays in table view

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        languageName = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "MyselectedLanguage") as? String //Your last selected language fetch
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }

    //MARK: - TableView
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return option.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = option[indexPath.row]

        if option[indexPath.row] == languageName{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        languageName = option[indexPath.row]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(languageName, forKey: "MyselectedLanguage")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        if let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appdelegate.showHomeLandingScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

**See the reference Image:**

[image]

Comment: You can change language array and register cell as your convenient and test it.